# Convert a column from string to Int in Dataframe

Tags: julia

Imagine I have a dataframe

```
df=DataFrame(A=rand(5),B=["8", "9", "4", "3", "12"])
```

What I want to do is to convert column B to Int type, so I used

```
df[!,:B] = convert.(Int64,df[!,:B])
```

But I got warning:

```
'Cannot Convert an object of type string to an object of type Int64'
```

Could you please tell me why I was wrong?

Comment: Note that it is enough to write `df.B` instead of `df[!, :B]` here and in the answers.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the [parse](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/numbers/#Base.parse) function, broadcast over the elements in the column with dot notation:

```
df = DataFrame(A = rand(5), B = ["8", "9", "4", "3", "12"])
df[!, :B] = parse.(Int64, df[!, :B])
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is `df[!,:B] = Int64.(df[!,:B])`. Convert is only defined between types where you can convert without losing information (ie in this case, you can't convert an arbitrary `string` to an `Int`)